# MVC gives a strange error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

The error message I'm getting is:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[MvcApplication1.ContentPageNav]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcApplication1.ContentPageNav'.

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
   DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
   var model = from m in dc.ContentPageNavs
      select m;
   return View(model);
}
```

Any ideas on why I get this error? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this(your code does not work because of you view wait for ContentPageNav item but you send a list of ContentPageNav):

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
   using(DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext())
   {
     // here you can select some specific item from the ContentPageNavs list
     // Following query take first item from the list
     var model = dc.ContentPageNavs.FirstOrDefault();
     return View(model);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are selecting a *list* of `ContentPageNav` into your `model` variable.

The view is expecting a `ContentPageNav`, not a list of them.

Try this:

```
var model = (from m in dc.ContentPageNavs
  select m).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Now I have put a where condition in my linq and I still get the same error. Query returns only one row

Comment: @sly_Chandan - A list of one item is not the same as one item.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your page is expecting a single ContentPageNav, not a LINQ expression. Try

```
return View(model.FirstOrDefault());
```

or

```
var model = dc.ContentPageNavs.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error indicates the types don't match. The view expects a single item but you are passing in a collection of items. Try passing this in as the model : `(from m in dc.ContentPageNavs select m).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at your view it is strongly typed. It should say something like

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc<ContentPageNav>"
```

if you need a list you may want to consider using

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc<IList<ContentPageNav>>"
```

or some kind of list ... your LINQ might be wrong though if this is not intended.